# Best way to validate certain words in textbox in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, regex, validation

I have a PIN textbox where I need to trigger a validation if user entered an Invalid PIN like 111111 or 000000. Already tried using CustomValidator with JS call but the "Invalid PIN" message doesn't go away after I type in the valid PIN. So I'm checking if this can be done in Validation Controls like RegularExpressionValidator. My question is can we add certain words in ValidationExpression? If so, what's the validation expression to prevent multiple words?

My aspx file

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvNewPIN" runat="server" 
     SetFocusOnError="true" ClientValidationFunction="IsPINValid" 
     ErrorMessage="Invalid PIN" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small" 
     Display="Dynamic">Invalid PIN</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPIN" runat="server" 
     TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
```

jQuery

```
function IsPINValid(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = true;

    var invalidPINs = "111111,000000";
    var arrInvalidPINs = invalidPINs.split(',');
    if (arrInvalidPINs.indexOf($('#<%=txtPIN.ClientID %>') > - 1)) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can like you mentioned use RegEx Validator and this could contain a list of words not allowed along with what needs validation.

Comment: I edited my question. It would be helpful if someone can provide the regex for preventing a list of words. I can't find anything regarding this but I'm still searching. Thanks

Comment: Are you using WebForms here? that's a blast from the past :)

Comment: Yes, I'm using WebForms here. This is an old system that I'm enhancing

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have the following statement is always true

```
 if (arrInvalidPINs.indexOf($('#<%=txtPIN.ClientID %>') > - 1))
```

You need to check `val` of Textbox as follows:

```
if (arrInvalidPINs.indexOf($('#<%=txtPIN.ClientID %>').val()) > - 1) {
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated my script but the problem is still that the error message of the customvalidator does not go away even if I inputted the valid PIN. No problem with the error handling, just that the behaviour of CustomValidator may cause confusion. What I just did is to set the Display="Dynamic" to None so it won't display the red message anymore. It will now only popup the message. Thanks!

Comment: You might need to add `ControlToValidate="txtPIN"` to your `CustomValidator`, could you try that if it works? 
    `<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvNewPIN" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPIN" SetFocusOnError="true" ClientValidationFunction="IsPINValid" ErrorMessage="Invalid PIN" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small" Display="Dynamic">Invalid PIN</asp:CustomValidator>`